# DTS Access via JET password problem

Tags: ms-access, dts

I have a DTS package on SQL 2000 that I haven't touched for three years. Package is running without problems every night and now I need to make some changes.

Package reads data from couple of Access files that have password set. When I open Access connection in DTS designer and click OK I get error message "not a valid password".

Why is password now wrong but when package runs every night it is valid? What am I missing?

EDIT - on another server I have SQL 2008. When I execute Import data, I can open Access files without any problems, just by specifying Jet OleDB:Database password (which is where password is set in DTS package).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to this problem - I wasn't logged on SQL server with the user that created (and owned) DTS package in question. Once I logged in with the same user as package owner, everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

The connection string at run time may be different than what it is in the package.

Your password could be in a config file or a variable.

Comment: You'll have to give me more than that. Note that password is valid even when designer raises error claiming that it is not.